# How to get the shell of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, image

I created an image in illustrator, which I have included here:

[image]

Note that the white space in this image is empty and is not a white color fill. I am importing this image as an SVG into illustrator. What I am trying to do is to take the tracing of this image, turn it into a mesh, and extrude it. However, whenever I import the image into blender, I get this:

[image]

Notice how the imported SVG fills in the shape instead of it just creating a tracing of this shape like I have created in illustrator. Is there any way for me to create a mesh where it is just the tracing of this image? Thanks in advance! Also let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: It's the opposite question but you should be able to unfill your curve using the answer

Comment: Not really, I don't know much about bezier curves unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Select the object, navigate to the curve properties (green arc icon in the lower right of your screen) and look for a property called *Fill Mode*. Set it to None.

[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: Hello! I think I understand how to do it now! Thank you! I am planning on extruding this as well. One question I do have - the stroke of the tracing I have above has a certain thickness - I was wondering if there was a way to emulate that instead of the curve just having an infinitesimally thin stroke?

Comment: Use another curve shaped as a rectangle as the bevel object of your own curve, so it will create a rectangular tube along your curve. Then you can set the size to the width you want.